# jqGrid getRowData returns empty object

Tags: jqgrid

when I call  $('#myId').jqGrid('getRowData', index), i just get back empty object.  If I call  $('#softwareCartGrid').jqGrid('getRowData')[index] I get the row object I expect.

Under what circumstances does  $('#myId').jqGrid('getRowData', index) fail in this manner?  I've hacked a workaroud to accomodate this, but, it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your question is that getRowData method have a parameter not a **index** of the row, but a rowID. If the rowId is not set getRowData return all the rows as array. If the rowID is not found, nothing is return.

The *index* you set is not valid **rowId** in grid, while returning a array in second case this index exists.

I highly recommend you before posting  a problem to look at the docs for the description of the method and the parameters passed.

Comment: Spent 90+ mins look at the docs.  What you are saying above is not apparent reading the documentation alone.  There is another part of our code where this: $('#myId').jqGrid('getRowData', index) *does* work, so apparently the rowid was being set in that case, but not in the code I am working with.  I'll look into that.

Comment: In this case, please provide a demo which demonstrates the problem, otherwise I can't help. By the way which version of jqGrid is used? - this is important too.Which documentation you have read? - please provide a link to it

Comment: We are using 4.6, the documentation I am using is here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods.

What I have found is this: when I said it works in another area, when I use $('#myId').jqGrid('getDataIDs') what is returned is ["1","2"].  In the case where ('getRowData', "rowId") returns empty object, ('getDataIDs') returns ["jqg1","jqg2"].  No idea how that happens, that is what I am looking into now.

Comment: The reason to return ["jqg1","jqg2"] is that your jqGrid does not have set a id or the id is not correct defined in the jsonReader. Be a sure that you have a valid jsonReader id set or the best is to define the id in colModel with key: true property